# When are bitwise operations appropriate

Tags: c#, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am aware of the basic premise of what bitwise operation are (although would appreciate a "for dummies" explanation); however I am unaware of when it is appropriate to use this technique.

My understanding is that [older CPU architectures could perform bitwise operations faster then other operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and hence it was advantageous to know how to use them. Given this is no longer the case; is it still appropriate to perform them and if so, for what purpose and under what conditions? (I am specifically interested in the C# context but am happy to receive general answers)

Comment: Do you mean shifts and such like, or all the logical operations too?

Comment: No shifts. I do understand logical operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitwise operations are a great way to quickly check for a flag that may be set on a variable.

The following example highlights the benefits of using bitwise operations on a `Flag` enumeration as well as storing a bitstuffed field into a database. The bitstuffed field can then easily be checked to see if it contains a single value or subset of values from the `Flag` enumeration.

**Example:**

A `User` database table with a `tinyint` field called `Permission`. The field is populated using a value created with the enumeration which values are 2^n.

```
[Flags]
public enum Permission : byte
{
    None = 0,
    ManageUsers = 1 << 0,
    CreateOrders = 1 << 1,
    PurchaseEquipment = 1 << 2,
    CancelOrders = 1 << 3,
}
```

Apart from bitwise operations being used to specify values in the enumeration (done at compile time), you can use the enumeration to check if the Permission field in the database contains any subset of the possible values. From the database side you gain the ability to stuff values into a single field - eliminating the need to have a column for each permission and in the code side you gain an easy way to check for a value.

**Example bitstuffing (Grant ManageUsers and CreateOrders):**

```
Permission userPermissions = Permission.ManageUsers | Permission.CreateOrders;
```

**Example permission check:**

```
public bool HasPermissions(Permission userPermissions, Permission permissionsToCheckFor)
{
    return permissionsToCheckFor == Permission.None ? 
        false : 
        (userPermissions & permissionsToCheckFor) == permissionsToCheckFor;
}
```

Comment: Thats an awesome example. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: @Maxim-Gershkovich isn't it a draw back that you will not immediately see what the userPermissions will be if you lookup the value in the database with a client

Comment: I agree with @HCP. Bitwise operators cause unnecessarily unreadable code when there are many other ways to encode this information.

1. speed/size optimization is the only true reason to use it, and unless you are doing embedded systems, I'd argue that there are very few legitimate reasons to need this kind of speed-up on most of today's systems.  The trade-off for readability and debug-ability would be well worth it for the speed in most large projects.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229058(v=vs.100).aspx):
The size savings might be significant if:  
    

    1. You expect the enumeration to be used as a field in a very frequently instantiated structure or class.  
    2. You expect users to create large arrays or collections of enumeration instances.  
    3. You expect a large number of instances of the enumeration to be serialized.

Comment: @m1m1k, given this example, how else would you _encode this information_? Surely you aren't suggesting a bit column for each permission? This example does not serve for **speed/size** optimization technique. It simply shows an easy way of managing permissions. That is it. Also, your reference to MSDN _is quoting irrelevant points_ that are not related to `Flag` enums at all! Finally, bitwise operations are as much a _core programming concept_ as [short circuit operations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13313135/498969). Both core concepts that are easy to follow and understand.

Comment: @m1m1k I just realized that you downvoted my answer too. My answer addressed the immediate question which is essentially "Is it still appropriate to use bitwise operations given today's technology improvements?" and this answer shows how it is still relevant today.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not so much that bitwise operations are faster than integer operation (although they usually are), it's that they are **different** operations for **different** purposes.

Conceptually bytes and shorts and ints are really tiny **arrays** of bits and bitwise operators are boolean array operators.  In C# nowadays bitwise operators are mostly used for `[Flags]` enumerations and in calculations for `GetHashCode` but there are endless ways that arrays of bits can be used.

Comment: +1. Practical example where I used bitwise opeartions - Base64/Base32 encoding/decoding code (data is considered to be array of bits encoded 6 or 5 bits at a time). More generally code for compression/decompression commonly uses bitwise opeartions treating data as on hige array of bits.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that just because language gives you bitwise operation, you should not use them just because you can.  I've seen people use bitwise operators when working with simple booleans and that's not what they are for.

Bitwise operators are useful when working with data structures where pieces of data are not aligned with byte boundary.  Generally, this is done when bandwidth (or general memory footprint) is very important.  I work on RTP video streaming software and bitwise operations are used both in reading/constructing RTP transmission packets as well as for reading video codec streams, which are often encoded using bits, not bytes.

Answer (score 2):

They can be really useful in embedded control situations when space is at a premium.  For example, a single byte of data can represent 8 i/o bits, and masks can be used to retrieve the bits of interest from an i/o port (e.g. if `PIN0 = 1, PIN1 = 2, PIN2 = 4, PIN3 = 8` and so on, then:

- To get the value of `PIN0`, we can say `PORT0 & PIN0 == 0`.
- To set `PIN1` to 1, we can cay `PORT0 |= PIN1`.
- To set `PIN2` to 0, we can say `PORT0 &= ~PIN2`.

Away from embedded control, I rarely see this approached used these days.  In the C# world it's much more common to see individual boolean fields for each value of interest, since the overhead is really not a big deal with modern hardware (though you may run into a case or two where bitwise operations are used to keep many such flags in a single variable).

There is also an interesting application in graphics.  A neat trick for cursors or bounding boxes is to add them by XOR'ing the cursor shape with the image below.  Performing the same operation again will result in the original image.

Answer (score 2):

One way I find myself using bitwise operators from time to time is to generate subsets of a given string/array using a binary mask, it goes like this: (sorry, c++ code)

```
string s = "abcde";
for(int i = 0; i < 1<<s.size(); i++) {
  string tmp;
  for(int j = 0; j < s.size(); j++) if(i & 1<<j) tmp.push_back(s[j]);
  cout<<tmp<<endl; 
}
```

You may want to check this insightful contests-oriented programming tutorial: [A bit of fun: fun with bits](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=bitManipulation)