# Boolean Or containing Ternary conditional operation doesn't get short-circuited

Tags: c#, .net, short-circuiting

In general, the short circuit `or` operator `||` ignores the right side of the or if the left side evaluates to true. Apparently, we've found an exception to this.

Check out the following:

```
if (foo == null || bar != true ? foo.Count == 0 : true)
{

}
```

This code throws a null reference exception on the command `foo.Count` because `foo` is null. And naturally, the boolean logic allows for this. But, if `foo` is null you would expect that the `or` would short circuit and not even evaluate the right side of the expression, but it still does, and it throws an exception.

Is this a bug in my code or in the C# compiler? Is there a part of the C# specification that handles this case?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add some code to setup the objects (`foo` and `bar`) as you are using them.

Comment: @m1m1k What exception is thrown?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker `This code throws a null reference exception on the command foo.Count`

Comment: Please avoid "begging the bug" in titles. Chances are high it's not the compiler/language/library.

Comment: This really is a messy way of laying out your conditional statements. You should be using parenthetical separations to explicitly describe what the order of operations is intended to be - even if you want the default behavior.

Comment: I would re-write that as `if(foo == null || bar || !foo.Any()))`.  I feel that it's much easier to read than your solution, even after adding more parenthesis to have it run as you intended.

Answer (score 17):

That's because your statement isn't being evaluated as you expect.

You need some extra parenthesis:

```
if(foo == null || (bar != true ? foo.Count == 0 : true))
```

The way it's written now is equivalent to (due to operator precedence):

```
if((foo == null || bar != true) ? foo.Count == 0 : true)
```

Answer (score 11):

No, it works correctly, refer to [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). `||` will be evaluated before `?:`

So it firstly evaluates `foo == null || bar != true` and then `? foo.Count == 0 : true`, so it's more like:

```
if ((foo == null || bar != true) ? foo.Count == 0 : true)
{

}
```

If you want to use short-circut here then it should be:

```
if (foo == null || (bar != true ? foo.Count == 0 : true))
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Imagine parentheses around the condition you're checking:

```
if ((foo == null || bar != true) ? foo.Count == 0 : true)
{

}
```

Thus, if `foo` is `null`, you're attempting to read `foo.Count`, which will naturally result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) conditional operator `?:` has lowest priority. Thus it will be executed last. Like this:

```
(foo == null || bar != true) ? foo.Count == 0 : true
```